# How can I use two collections in one reactive table? Meteor Js

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I wanna use two collections in one reactive table using meteorjs. I have two collections and I want to merge these collection in single table. I have no clues please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on `reywood:publish-composite` package. It allows you to publish reactive joins.

https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite

Answer (score 0):

When using reactive-table you can use a [dynamic column](https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table#dynamic-columns) which allows you to define a *function* for a column. You can then use this function to lookup data in another collection.

Example:

```
{ fieldId: 'someOtherThing', // needs to be unique in your table
  key: 'otherId', // this should be the _id of the other collection you want to "join"
  label: 'Some Label',
  fn: function(_id){
    const otherObject = OtherCollection.findOne(_id);
    if ( otherObject ) return otherObject.someKey;
  }
},
```